# What exactly is the difference between code first and database first approach in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I don't know when use code-first and database-first approach.

I am already working with both code-first and database-first, I know how they work but my question is when to use code-first and database-first?

Today I had an interview and the interviewer asked me what the difference between code-first and database-first approach is.

Me: when you working with small application then use code first and when you working with large application then use database first

Again interviewer asked me what the difference between code first and database first approach is.

Me: in code first approach you don't need to create a table means design a table in class and add a connection string in web.config **and** database first approach you need to create a table and database

Again interviewer asked me what the difference between code first and database first approach is.

me:silent

Again interviewer asked me which situation I use code first and database first approach

me:silent

Answer (score 0):

> when you working with small application then use code first and when you working with large application then use database first

Your answer is a fair rule-of-thumb, but this is incorrect because **it doesn't answer the question**: "what is the *difference*`. This answers the *unasked* question "when would you use code-first vs. database-first" (though your interviewer did ask this question right at the very end).

> in code first approach you don't need to create a table means design a table in class and add a connection string in web.config and database first approach you need to create a table and database

This is correct - but you're describing it in-terms of the developer-experience, rather than what Entity Framework is actually doing behind-the-scenes.

---

A better description of the differences would be:

- **Database-first**:

  - The database is the **canonical** definition of the EF data store design.

    - So you should store your database design as an SSDT project in source-control!
  - EF is also aware of your C# entity types and maps your SQL database to your C# types using an `*.edmx` file.

    - Even though EF6 and EF Core no-longer use an EDMX file in your codebase, EF still uses EDMX internally.
- **Code-first**:

  - Your C# entity types are the **canonical** source-of-truth for the EF data store, and EF handles instantiating the actual SQL database.

Note that you can use EF Migrations and entity type Scaffolding with both Database-first and Code-first approaches.

Comment: one is important differance which i found in my work  code first - when you update your class then no need to more time database first - when you update entity then take the more time that is the biggest differance which I find